# Quarkus: Data source custom credentials provider

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, quarkus

How can I create a custom data source credentials provider that for example reads the credentials from a file on the disk? I need a way to set the credentials from code. I guess that's the way to go in Quarkus.

quarkus.datasource.username=I want to set this in the code

quarkus.datasource.password=I want to set this in the code

I only see a hashicorp vault integration. I need a way to do this in a custom credentials provider. I can see that there is a way to set the class that represent your provider but what interface that class should implement?

From the docs:

quarkus.datasource.credentials-provider=?

quarkus.datasource.credentials-provider-type=?

The credentials provider type. It is the @Named value of the credentials provider bean. It is used to discriminate if multiple CredentialsProvider beans are available. For Vault it is: vault-credentials-provider. Not necessary if there is only one credentials provider available.

Can somebody please help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this pattern is now officially supported in https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/9032 and documented in https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/9552

Answer (score 3):

Interesting. We have designed that contract with only Vault in mind so the interface is called io.quarkus.vault.CredentialsProvider and is in the quarkus-vault-spi module.

That being said, I think you could just add that module to your project (it doesn't have any Vault dependency). Then you could just implement that interface and things should be OK.

Your `CredentialsProvider` needs to be a CDI bean so you should make it either `@Singleton` or `@ApplicationScoped`.

Then you would just need to define a value for `quarkus.datasource.credentials-provider=<value here>`. The name is passed to the crendentials provider and is used in the case of Vault.

In your case, it just needs to be defined.

If it works for you, could you open an issue in our tracker? I think we should make that interface part of the datasource extension and not Vault specific.

UPDATE: I created an example project here: https://github.com/gsmet/quarkus-credentials-provider . Just run mvn clean install (you need Docker) and you'll see your CredentialsProvider being called.

Comment: I've implemented that interface but the method never got called @Override public Properties getCredentials(String credentialsProviderName)

Comment: in my properties cfg I've added only this as you suggested quarkus.datasource.credentials-provider=dummyname and I've also added the @ApplicationScoped to the provider impl. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think it should work. I'll try to prepare a simple project to see how it goes.

Comment: Thx Guillaume Smet. That will be a lifesaver

Comment: I see why I couldn't make this work. I'm using the reactive postgres API. Can you please help with this because the whole project is built on top of reactive? I've prepared a PR for your repo so that you can see what I'm doing https://github.com/gsmet/quarkus-credentials-provider/pull/1

Comment: Yes the `CredentialsProvider` is not supported for reactive datasources. I created https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/8878 . In the meantime, if you want to avoid having the credentials in your application, you can use environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, o.quarkus.vault.CredentialsProvider is meant to be HashiCorp Vault neutral.
Please see this issue for some guidance: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6896#issuecomment-581014674

Comment: Is there a way to be able to do that without creating a new extension? I just need to provide the credentials within the code. Why is this so difficult? I've tried implementing CredentialsProvider and spicified quarkus.datasource.credentials-provider=dummyname but my CustomCredentialsProvider never got called....